# ajax on elements not working for appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I have the following javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[class^="commentbubble_"]').click(function () { 
      var ID = $(this).attr('class').replace('commentbubble_', '');
        $('.commentform_'+ID).toggle();
        $('#commentsection').masonry( 'reload' );
    });
  });
</script>
```

It works for the first page of results...but for newly appended, it won't work.  Is there a way to ensure this function works on newly appended content?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with delegation the event to its parent which was available on page load or `$(document)` itself with `.on()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '[class^="commentbubble_"]', function () { 
      var ID = $(this).attr('class').replace('commentbubble_', '');
      $('.commentform_'+ID).toggle();
      $('#commentsection').masonry( 'reload' );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$().ready only works on the current elements

When you append an element you need bind is click event

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending data on ajax load after page is loaded, So you need to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler to bind any event on the element instead of .click event.

Syntax is :

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

So your script will be something like this :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('document).on('click','[class^="commentbubble_"]',function () { 
      var ID = $(this).attr('class').replace('commentbubble_', '');
        $('.commentform_'+ID).toggle();
        $('#commentsection').masonry( 'reload' );
    });
  });
</script>
```

For more reference, refer http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

`('[class^="commentbubble_"]').live ('click', function () {`

Note:
`live` is deprecated, use `on` as suggested by @Jai